# I want to make my glass transparent and reflective

Tags: transparency

I using Blender 2.9 with Cycles render.
I want make a texture glass with a transparent and reflective, but I can't make it work.

I search with google, but I only found a no texture tutorial.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the no texture tutorial? It is likely that after making that node setup all you have to do is plug in the image texture.

Comment: Then where should it be placed of texture?

Comment: Likely the color input.

Comment: Just use the glass shader. If you want to add an image texture on top read the following: [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)